# need help on Button event

Tags: c#, sql, 3-tier

I have used a 3-tier architecture to insert into database.I dont Know what code should i write on button click event in .cs file.Can some1 please help me?

Extension.cs

```
    public static DbParameter CreateAndSetParameter(this DbCommand cmd,string parameterName,DbType dbtype,int size,ParameterDirection direction)
{
    DbParameter p = cmd.CreateParameter();
    p.ParameterName = parameterName;
    p.DbType =dbtype;
    p.Size = size;
    p.Direction = direction;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(p);
    return p;
}
public static DbParameter CreateAndSetParameter(this DbCommand cmd, string parameterName, DbType dbtype, int size,object value)
{
    DbParameter p = cmd.CreateParameter();
    p.ParameterName = parameterName;
    p.DbType = dbtype;
    p.Size = size;
    p.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
    p.Value = value;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(p);
    return p;
}
```

DataGeneric.cs

```
     public static int AddSlider(string @Imgname,string @Imgalt)
    {
    int rows=-1;
    string Query="insert into [slider](ImageName,ImageAlt) values(@Imgname,@Imagealt)";
    DbCommand cmd = DataGeneric.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = Query;
    cmd.CreateAndSetParameter("@Imgname",DbType.String,50,Imgname);
    cmd.CreateAndSetParameter("@Imgalt", DbType.String, 50, Imgalt);
    rows = DataGeneric.ExecuteNonQuery(cmd);
    return rows;
    }
```

Design:

```
    ImageName:<asp:TextBox id="txt_name" runat="server" /><br />
    ImageAlt:<asp:TextBox ID="txt_alt" runat="server" />
    <asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" onclick="btn_Click" Text="Insert" />
```

Code:

```
    protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ????????????
}
```

Comment: check my answer you dnt supply connection to the command

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

   DataGeneric.AddSlider(txt_name.Text,txt_alt.Text);

}
```

as Addslider is a static method you can directly call that method using the class name

modify your addslider methos

```
public static int AddSlider(string Imgname,string Imgalt)
{
int rows=-1;
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("connection string");
conn.Open();
string Query="insert into [slider](ImageName,ImageAlt) values(@Imgname,@Imagealt)";
DbCommand cmd = DataGeneric.CreateCommand();
cmd.Connection = conn;
cmd.CommandText = Query;
cmd.CreateAndSetParameter("@Imgname",DbType.String,50,Imgname);
cmd.CreateAndSetParameter("@Imgalt", DbType.String, 50, Imgalt);
rows = DataGeneric.ExecuteNonQuery(cmd);
conn.Close();
return rows;
}
```

Comment: Thanks  in advance....I ws using separate class for connection & provider name...& now using ur method its throwing the exception _Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0._

Comment: i just added the connection open